# Give One Subscription Priority Over Other Subscriptions

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

I use logical replication to synchronize one big table + some small tables.

I know that if all tables are part of the same subscription it will be executed in transactional order. In other words, as long as the transaction that updated the big table is not synchronized and executed on the subscriber side, no other transactions to the smaller tables will be synchronized to the subscriber side.

How can I give higher priority to the subscription that synchronizing the smaller tables over the subscription that synchronizes the large table?  If that is not possible, how do I make sure the subscription that synchronizes the big table does not "starve" the subscription that synchronizes the small tables and leave it with almost no bandwidth?

Comment: Are all these tables in one publication?  One subscription? Are the updates to the several tables all in one transaction?

Comment: Yes, I was not clear.  I modified my question.  Thanks